# What can cause a Layer 2 Switch to drop frames that aren't malformed?

Tags: cisco, switch, layer2

Recently I replaced a defect Desktop switch with a cisco SG-200-8 switch. After I replaced the old switch everything seemed to work fine. Now the employees have trouble using the scanner through TWAIN. After some hours I figured out that using an unmanaged switch the scanning process works fine.

I then scanned some pages and captured the network traffic. There are no malformed frames so I don't see any reason why the switch should drop the frames. Can somebody make sense out of this?

// After many checks I now can specify the problem further. The SYN Packet that is send from the client to the printer is dropped by the switch. Anyway Etherlike does not display any dropped frames. The Packet looks like this:

[image]

// As I wasn't able to make any sense from this behavior I think this might be a bug in the firmware. In the release of one firmware update a similar bug is patched that is related to printing. This is not exactly my problem but it aims broadly in the right direction. I will report back if this fixed it.

// After two firmware updates the problem is solved.

Comment: What do the switch interfaces say about errors?

Comment: Sadly the don't say anything

Comment: Edit your question to include the output on the switch interface.

Comment: You mean the packet capture? Or the logged information?

Comment: No. In the switch, you can show the interface. It will give you all the statistics, including errors it sees.

Comment: Also, "employees have trouble" is rather broad, can you clarify in more detail? And, where/how did you take the capture? If you capture on your PC then of course it will not show any frames that got sent by the scanner but dropped by the switch.

Comment: This is the command: `show interface ethernet {interface | switchport}`. Do this for the interface to which the scanner is connected.

Comment: in the SG-200 series there is no console in the SG-200 series...

Comment: You can telnet to the switch. It has CLI. The command I gave you was directly from the SG200 CLI manual.

Comment: Does your TWAIN driver use only unicast communication or is there some multicast discovery process involved?

Comment: @RonMaupin That is only valid for the 220 and above. The 200 does not have a CLI and I can't telnet in. (https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12389791/enabling-telnet-sg200-50fp)

Comment: @marctxk it only uses unicast.

Comment: If you can't use CLI, then what does the **Etherlike Statistics** page say about interface errors?

Comment: Any switch, managed or unmanaged, will drop bad frames.

Comment: When using the SG-200, do the flows fail completely or are they just slow?  I'd like to see the network capture.

Comment: See edit for further information

Comment: I'm assuming this is a capture on the PC that's trying to use the scanner.  Nothing jumps out of the trace, you already have two-way packet flow between the two devices.  If it were me I'd want to put taps on the two cables to make sure that: it is the SYN that's being dropped (not the SYNACK); it is the switch that's dropping it.  However I wouldn't buy two taps for the privilege, it's just too costly compared to the problem when you already have a work-around.

Comment: this has been captured from a tap between the switch and the pc. I also put a tap between the switch and the scanner. The frame did not reach the scanner!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the switch - a layer 2 device - is dropping packets based on layer 4 information.  Some possible explanations:  1.  The Syn packet has a bad checksum (you don't have  checksum validation turned on), 2.  The SYN is getting through but the SYN-ACK isn't.   Can you capture packets on the other side of the switch?

Comment: @RonTrunk, David's done that and he knows that the frame didn't come out of the switchport that the printer's on.  The options now are: it was dropped; it was forwarded out through another port.  If it was dropped there should be a counter or there's a bug, if it was forwarded through another port then there was a MAC table change or a bug or the PC has suddenly used the wrong MAC address (still with a Ricoh OUI and existing in the table otherwise it'd be flooded, easy to check).  Hard to believe in a MAC change just after the SNMP got through, especially if it's repeatable.

Comment: @marctxk Another thing to check is to turn on checksum validation on Wireshark -- it's rare, but I've seen devices miscalculate checksums.

Comment: @RonTrunk, I agree about devices getting checksums wrong but a switch should only drop on bad FCS, not on IP or TCP/UDP checksums, that's for routers/endpoints to worry about.  If it does drop for a bad FCS then the drop should be counted.  Bad FCS frames are not captured by Wireshark on a normal PC unless the NIC driver is specifically capable and set, if it's a dedicated analyser then they will be.  Anyway David tells us that the packet is not malformed.  This is a wierd one that's for sure.

Comment: I start to belive that this is actually a bug in the firmware. Im doing a firmware update and will report back if that worked out,...

Comment: The problem was solved by a firmware update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem could be solved by doing a firmware update. After the update the scanning process works fine now.